# share feature of menu in android application

Tags: android

i asked so many question regarding my title but i could not get my proper answer till yet.I need to implement androd's menu feature in my application ie when we goes to gallery in android phone, when we press menu than it comes with lots of option like share...etc.My question is can i implement same menu feature in my application? It is possible or not?
Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to give more detail about what you're asking. If generating menus (as the link Bactos gave to the official Android guide explains how to do), then what *are* you asking?

Comment: You've asked this question several times and gotten some decent answers regarding intent choosers and opening menus. If you want something more specific, simply repeating the question won't help.

Comment: Now you have a well accepted answer. Ans yet you have not marked it. Its a shame.

Answer (score 8):

To implement a "Share" feature, all you need to do is use `createChooser()` and an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

[Here is a blog post](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/02/a-call-to-action-action_send-that-is/) covering the technique.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question you want to know if you can duplicate the feature of tapping on the menu button on the phone and having it pull up an options menu that you can then share via, gmail or some other posting medium?

If this is correct then I would have to say I would assume that you could duplicate this feature.

In short YES!

If you are wondering how you are to do this then I would start at here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Droidnova .com (I posted it like this because as a new user I can only post one link) also has a good little how to on menu's.

I would also like to add that this is my first time posting on stackoverflow so please let me know if this was a good post or what I should do next time.

Thanks,

Bactos

Comment: Sorry to say that i am not looking for your answer.
Thank you so much