# Share menu android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [share feature of menu in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407108/share-feature-of-menu-in-android-application)

Hello I want to do this share menu in my app but I don´t know how. There is a manual or a code to help me. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your first stop: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple menu with this tutorial :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

After that you can easily change the style (Transparent, ....) and also force displaying the menu without any action !

And for the Quickaction Dialog, read this tutorial :

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Hope it helps you